# What is the subspace of the particular solution to $Ax = b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I solve the equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 4 \\ -4\end{bmatrix}
$$

I get

$$
x
 = x_p + x_n
 = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
 + c \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

I was expecting the particular solution $x_p$ to be in the rowspace of $A$, the first two rows, but that doesn't seem to be the case:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
 \sim \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $\sim$ means row equivalent, so there's a full set of pivots meaning the particular solution $x_p$ is not a linear combination of the two rows spanning the rowspace and therefore not in the rowspace. If this is correct, what is the subspace of the particular solution?

Comment: Why were you expecting the particular solution to be in the row space?

Comment: Because I can use the particular solution on each row. For example, $x_p$ times the first row is $2\times 1 + -1\times 2 + 0\times 1 = 0$. Also, by process of elimination, the rowspace would seem to make the most sense but apparently not.

Comment: "What is the **subspace** of the particular solution to $Ax=b$" is a very strange/poor way of wording the question as the **set** of solutions to $Ax=b$ is not necessarily a *subspace*.  A subspace must contain $0$, but for $b\neq 0$ clearly $x=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: By "using" you seem to mean "take the dot (or matrix) product", but I am not sure what that has got to do with anything here.

Comment: Perhaps the shortest answer is that $x_p^\top$ will on occasion be in $Row(A)$ and will on occasion not be in $Row(A)$.  You exhibit here an example of when it is not.  An easy example of when it is is when $A=I$.  In general, it need not necessarily be in any of the fundamental subspaces of the matrix and does not have to have anything to do with them.

Comment: The only thing I can say for sure about it, is that $x_p$ will not be in $\ker(A)$ (except when $x_p=0$) by definition of it being a particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is not contained in the row space, there is exactly one particular solution which is. After all, $\text{row}(A)$ is the orthogonal complement to $\text{null}(A)$, which implies that $\mathbb{R}^n = \text{row}(A) \oplus \text{null}(A)$ where $\text{row}(A)\perp \text{null}(A)$. Thus, each vector $\boldsymbol{x} \in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as a unique sum $\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{x}_r + \boldsymbol{x}_n$ where $\boldsymbol{x}_r\in \text{row}(A)$, $\boldsymbol{x}_n\in \text{null}(A)$, and $\boldsymbol{x}_r\cdot\boldsymbol{x}_n=0$. By direct calculation, $\boldsymbol{x}_p$ listed above is not in the row space. The orthogonal projection $\mathbb{R}^3\to \text{row}(A)$ as the standard matrix of the form $P=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$, where $B^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ (where the rows of $B^T$ give a basis for $\text{row}(A)$). Note next that 
$$\boldsymbol{x}_r = P\boldsymbol{x}_p = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Note that $\boldsymbol{x}_r$ is a solution to the system since $A\boldsymbol{x}_r = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}$. Additionally, $\boldsymbol{x}_r = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + (-1) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol{x}_p + \boldsymbol{x}_n$. Finally, $\boldsymbol{x}_r = \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2\\ 1\end{bmatrix} + \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \in \text{row}(A)$. Hence, we have constructs a particular solution which lies in the row space and this is the only particular solution which lies in the row space. It does not necessarily correspond to the final column of the row-reduced echelonr form of the augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{c|c} A & \boldsymbol{b} \end{array}\right]$ though.

Comment: Alternatively, the particular solution lying in the row space is the "shortest vector" in the solution set. To find this, one could simply dot the general solution to the linear system found from row reduction with the general vector of the null space. Solving this resulting linear system would also produce the particular solution contained in the row space.